# How to install JRE 7u60 on Ubuntu 14.04 using the tar.gz file?

Tags: 14.04, java, tar, jre

How do I install JRE without PPAs or anything but the tar.gz file I downloaded from: http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp?locale=en

Answer (score 0):

If there is a shell file inside, run that after unzipping, otherwise, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware for compiling the software so long as it is the source code.

Comment: That doesn't work. (or I don't know how to do it properly) There is no ReadMe file with commands to use, ./Configure doesn't do anything, neither does 'make'

Comment: I'll download it and see what exactly its comprised of

Comment: looking at the instructions page, just follow those, they outline the procedure completely. If you want I can try and find a deb file if the other method isn't to your liking

Comment: I installed it according to those instructions at /usr/java but I can't run Java apps on Chrome. (RuneScape)

Comment: I installed JRE by following this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre/56119#56119  It still does not work on Chrome though. Works on Firefox however.